# How to configure option --with-libdir with PHP5.5

Tags: php, build

I'm building PHP5.5 with ldap support.

I've a 64bits system, so my libs are into `/usr/lib64`

So when I build PHP I add the following option:  `--with-libdir=/usr/lib64`

But When I run the configure tool, I get the following error:

```
configure: error: Cannot find ldap libraries in /usr//usr/lib64
```

Anybody know how absolute path works for these options?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have libraries in right dir, and you set the right `--with-libdir`

Try install `-devel` version

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of see the issue from the error. It's already looking in `/usr`, so you just need to put:

```
--with-libdir=lib64
```